# Interleave two lists of different length in python v. 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a Python function that takes two lists as arguments and interleaves them.  The order of the component lists should be preserved.  If the lists do not have the same length, the elements of the longer list should end up at the
end of the resulting list.
For example, I'd like to put this in Shell:

```
interleave(["a", "b"], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

And get this back:

```
["a", 1, "b", 2, 3, 4]
```

If you can help me I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it, using various bits of the `itertools` module. It works for any number of iterables, not just two:

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest # or zip_longest in Python 3
def interleave(*iterables):

    sentinel = object()
    z = izip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue = sentinel)
    c = chain.from_iterable(z)
    f = filter(lambda x: x is not sentinel, c)

    return list(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
In [30]: from itertools import izip_longest

In [31]: l = ['a', 'b']

In [32]: l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [33]: [item for slist in izip_longest(l, l2) for item in slist if item is not None]
Out[33]: ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 3, 4]
```

`izip_longest` 'zips' the two lists together, but instead of stopping at the length of the shortest list, it continues until the longest one is exhausted:

```
In [36]: list(izip_longest(l, l2))
Out[36]: [('a', 1), ('b', 2), (None, 3), (None, 4)]
```

You then add items by iterating through each item in each pair in the zipped list, omitting those that have a value of `None`. As pointed out by @Blckknight, this will not function properly if your original lists have `None` values already. If that is possible in your situation, you can use the `fillvalue` property of `izip_longest` to fill with something other than `None` (as @Blckknight does in his answer).

Here is the above example as a function:

```
In [37]: def interleave(*iterables):
   ....:     return [item for slist in izip_longest(*iterables) for item in slist if item is not None]
   ....:

In [38]: interleave(l, l2)
Out[38]: ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 3, 4]

In [39]: interleave(l, l2, [44, 56, 77])
Out[39]: ['a', 1, 44, 'b', 2, 56, 3, 77, 4]
```

Comment: Your version won't work with lists that contain `None` as values. That's why I created a unique sentinel object in my version, so it won't trip over any weird values already in the list.

Comment: @Blckknght Gotcha - your version is nice, I do agree :) I'll edit the answer to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

A not very elegant solution, but still may be helpful

```
def interleave(lista, listb):
    (tempa, tempb) = ([i for i in reversed(lista)], [i for i in reversed(listb)])
    result = []
    while tempa or tempb:
        if tempa:
            result.append(tempa.pop())
        if tempb:
            result.append(tempb.pop())

    return result
```

or in a single line

```
   def interleave2(lista, listb):
    return reduce(lambda x,y : x + y,
                  map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1],
                      [(lista[i:i+1], listb[i:i+1])
                       for i in xrange(max(len(lista),len(listb)))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is based on: *How would I do it by hand?* Well, almost by hand, using the built-in `zip()`, and extending the result of zipping the in the length of the shorter list by the tail of the longer one:

```
#!python2

def interleave(lst1, lst2):
    minlen = min(len(lst1), len(lst2))        # find the length of the shorter
    tail = lst1[minlen:] + lst2[minlen:]      # get the tail
    result = []
    for t in zip(lst1, lst2):                 # use a standard zip
        result.extend(t)                      # expand tuple to two items
    return result + tail                      # result of zip() plus the tail

print interleave(["a", "b"], [1, 2, 3, 4])
print interleave([1, 2, 3, 4], ["a", "b"])
print interleave(["a", None, "b"], [1, 2, 3, None, 4])
```

It prints the results:

```
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 3, 4]
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 4]
['a', 1, None, 2, 'b', 3, None, 4]
```